# BroadcastReceiver, Service and Wakelock

Tags: android, wakelock, android-wake-lock

im receiving an intent in broadcast receiver and then i start service to do more work. now what if the device is sleep and this happen, do i have to get Wakelock (AlarmManger?), and why do i need it?
does my service will stop running if the device goes to sleep without getting a wakelock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> now what if the device is sleep and this happen, do i have to get Wakelock (AlarmManger?), and why do i need it?

If the device is asleep to begin with, you will not be "receiving an intent in broadcast receiver", because the device is asleep.

> do i have to get Wakelock (AlarmManger?), and why do i need it?

You don't "need it", unless you want to ensure the device stays running while you complete some work.

> does my service will stop running if the device goes to sleep without getting a wakelock.

Yes.

Comment: for the first part, i meant i will receive an intent from C2DM which i guess you could receive it while the device is asleep. and then i want to run a service and i guess i have to get wakelock to keep it running. is these assumption are correct ?

Comment: @Fevos: "i meant i will receive an intent from C2DM which i guess you could receive it while the device is asleep." -- yes, C2DM uses a socket connection over wireless data (AFAIK), and incoming packets on that connection will wake up the device *briefly*. "and then i want to run a service and i guess i have to get wakelock to keep it running. is these assumption are correct ?" -- yes, you will want your own `WakeLock`. Just be sure to release it when you are done.

Comment: "If the device is asleep to begin with, you will not be "receiving an intent in broadcast receiver", because the device is asleep." Where this is documented?

Comment: @MarianPaździoch: "Where this is documented?" -- I doubt that it is documented specifically, in part because it is obvious. If the CPU is not executing instructions, nobody's broadcast `Intent` is going to be processed. You are welcome to read the documentation on `PowerManager` and `PowerManager.WakeLock` to learn more about CPU states.

Comment: @CommonsWare I wouldn't use word OBVIOUS in context of Android :). So if it's obviuos that BroadcastReceiver keeps device PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK then is it also obvious that IntentService also keeps device PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK?

Comment: @MarianPaździoch: "So if it's obviuos that BroadcastReceiver keeps device PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK" -- it does not keep a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`. "IntentService also keeps device PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK?" -- it too does not keep a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`. That is why the Android Support package has `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` and I wrote `WakefulIntentService`.

Comment: @CommonsWare "If the device is asleep to begin with, you will not be "receiving an intent in broadcast receiver", because the device is asleep." I've found definition of contrary here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396766/do-i-need-to-acquire-wake-lock-when-invoking-a-broadcast-service

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the Android's native [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) would be a perfect solution for you. Need to extend this rather than the regular *BroadcastReceiver* and start the service in the *onReceive()* in the "wakeful" manner:

```
startWakefulService(context, service);
```

and signal your work is done in the service's *onHandleIntent()*, calling

```
MyWakefulReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class WakeLockManager extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static WakeLock mWakeLock;
    private String LCLT;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Consts.WAKELOCK_INTENT)) {
            Log.v("wakelock", "GOT THE wakelock INTENT");
            boolean on = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("on");
            if (mWakeLock == null) {
                PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                        "Breeze WakeLock");
            }
            if (on) {
                if (!mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
                    mWakeLock.acquire();
                    Log.v("wakelock", "acquiring wakelock");
                }
            } else {
                if (mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
                    Log.v("wakelock", "releasing wakelock");
                    mWakeLock.release();
                }
                mWakeLock = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

look at the above code ..put it in a separate class file and and in your manifest define it for some custom intent .... now that this class will respond to a custom intent ...just broadcast that intent and you can turn the wakelock on or off in your entire app since the wakelock is static..like this :

```
public void setWakeup(boolean status) {
    Intent wakelock_Intent = new Intent(CUSTOM_INTENT);
    wakelock_Intent.putExtra("on", status);
    this.sendBroadcast(wakelock_Intent);
}
```

the above would be defined ***in your alarmmanager code so it schedules a call***

Comment: Are you sure this "static lock" won't be wiped away when the Receiver `class` is unloaded ? See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299283/broadcastreciever-life-cycle-static-variables#comment7376537_6299862

Comment: I am assuming the object will not be garbage collected as this is not an anonymous broadcastReceiver.  If i allocate this object myself and maintain a hard reference to it why would it free'd by the system  ? this is a interesting topic please advise.