# Android : Stopping works Widget when user removes app from recent tasks list

Tags: android, android-appwidget, timertask

I have a Timer in my app widget. This timer will be updating the Widget UI every second. All the process works perfectly. But, when user removes my app from recently apps task list, timer stops immediately.

Anybody knows how to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you using a Service to run the Timer?

Comment: No, I'm not use service, i will be start timer in the method "onUpdate". Timer is a static field.

Comment: As I have done a similar project in past, that way it would not work.
I had tried your solution and the timer was stopping after some time, no matter what. I'll put some suggestions in an answer.

Comment: I have a list Timer tasks and when first task ended and second timer task will be run if stack list not empty

Comment: I don't understand why timer stopped

Comment: when user removes my app from recently apps task list, its process is killed. thats why the Timer stops

Answer (score 1):

Put your logic for controlling the `Widget` in a `Service`. in `onStartCommand()` method, start a time scheduler thing, or register for `ACTION_TIME_TICK` which will send an event, every minute.

Also remember to return `START_STICKY` from your `Service` so that the OS can restart the service in cases where your process gets closed by the OS itself or by swiping away from recent task list.

One caveat is that restarting the service after swiping from recents would not happen in KitKat Android duo to a bug. Though there's a dirty workaround for it.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6299862/2511775

The `BroadcastReceiver` object gets cleaned up pretty quickly. And `AppWidgetProvider` is a child of `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: @Sarlak I tired your idea but not working, I return START_STICKY but OS not restarted Service