# Android BroadcastReceiver's onReceive sometimes not called

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, android-geofence

My apps uses `BroadcastReceiver` with `Geofencing API`. The `BroadcastReceiver` will be called when the user entering a `Geofence`.

Yesterday, the code works flawlessly. The `BroadcastReceiver` detect me *entering a Geofence which i set around my place* by this code :

```
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
```

The `Geofence` `setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)` and `radius` is `1609` Meter (1 Mile)

Today, i uninstalled the apps and run the **exact same code** again, on the **same computer** and **same device**. I stumbled upon the fact my `BroadcastReceiver`'s `onReceive` never getting called.

I checked the internet connection which is fine. I tried to `clean`, `rebuild`, and `make project` on the `android studio` and manually uninstall the `APK` before running the `android studio` but the `BroadcastReceiver` still not working.

**There is an important point i found out** :

The `breakpoint` i put inside `onReceive` is enabled (plain red) but **not valid** (red with checkmark). This is the [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/breakpoints-icons-and-statuses.html) of what i mean.

**Yesterday** (when the exact same code is working), the **breakpoint** is **valid**.

Then i tried to use the `IntentService` instead of `BroadcastReceiver` (i will share the code of both of them later in this question). The `IntentService` is called hence my `PendingIntent` is working.

After that, i tried to use the `BroadcastReceiver` again, and the `BroadcastReceiver` is working perfectly like yesterday. Now, sometimes the `BroadcastReceiver` is called sometimes not.

**The strange part is** i need to change the `PendingIntent` to `IntentService` everytime my `BroadcastReceiver` not working to make my `BroadcastReceiver` start working again.

And once it start working again, the `BroadcastReceiver` still called even with smaller (250 Meter) `radius`. So i think the `radius` is not the problem.

I tried to debug the `onReceive` and found out **the `breakpoint` must be `valid` (not just `enabled`) to make my `BroadcastReceiver` working.** In other words, if the breakpoint is just `enabled` (not `valid`) then the `onReceive` will never be called.

This is how i call the `BroadcastReceiver` :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("mypackage.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE");
    PendingIntent geofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
            mGoogleApiClient,
            getGeofencingRequest(),
            geofencePendingIntent
    ).setResultCallback(this);
```

And this is how i call the `IntentService` :

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceUpdateService.class);
        PendingIntent geofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                getGeofencingRequest(),
                geofencePendingIntent
        ).setResultCallback(this);
```

And this is my `manifest`, which contain both of `IntentService` and `BroadcastReceiver` :

```
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name="mypackage.GeofenceUpdateService" />

        <receiver android:name="mypackage.GeofenceUpdateReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="mypackage.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I **do not** post the `onReceive` or `onHandleIntent` because the problem is not inside those code, but **why those method sometimes not getting called**.

How to make my `BroadcastReceiver` work more stable? (always working)

Or is there any workaround? Should i just use `IntentService` instead?

Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: after fresh installation of app, have you started the app manually? Sometimes it dont work if you dont start the app first.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The apps will run automatically because i run it from `android studio`, what i mean by `manually` is i uninstall the old`APK` before running the new one from `android studio`.

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer as it seems that you are not familiar with how Android works [Do I need to acquire wake lock when invoking a BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396766/do-i-need-to-acquire-wake-lock-when-invoking-a-broadcastreceiver).

And then use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` instead of `BroadcastReceiver` and check if it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.  I do make sure the device is still wake up (screen not sleep) when i tested my `BroadcastReceiver`. I will try to use `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` and let you know